# How to access current User and database context in .net core Model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a model with a method and I want to get the current UserID and have access to the database context.

```
public class Annonce
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    ...

    public bool AnnonceDansFavoris(UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager)
    {
        // Recherche du user ID courant
        string userID = UserManager.GetUserId(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        var _context = (PatrimoineClickDbContext)ValidationContext.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));

        
        return (_context.Favoris.Any(f => (f.CreePar == userID) && (f.AnnonceID == ID)));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work :(

Can you tell me how I can do this.

Thanks

Here's my error messages

[I can't have access to the User property of the HttpContext Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU8hc.png)

[I can't access to ValidationContext.GetService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNCmR.png)

Comment: "It doesn't work" with no exception/error details Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were passing wrong parameter:
[image]
To Get UserId you could try:

```
var principle = HttpContext.User;
            
string userID = UserManager.GetUserId(principle);
```

To get context in your custom ValidationAttribute:

```
var _context = (ApplicationDbContext)ValidationContext.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));
```

I think it may help if you could describe your purpose more clearly and share more codes related